# regular expression to remove substring and all characters after x

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having problems with a regular expression. I have a string like this:

```
/Date(-62135596800000+0100)/
```

I would like to remove everything up until and including the opening parenthesis and everything after the + sign, so far I've come up with this:

```
 [\/Date(]|\+(.*)
```

Which has two issues, 1) it is matching the single characters /, D, a etc. instead of matching the substring '/Date(' and 2) it throws and error when using replace like so:

```
function returnNewString(oldString) {
    var re = [\/Date(]|+(.*),
    output = oldString.replace(re,'');
    return output;
}
```

I'm rather new to reg-ex so the above might be wrong in every way possible so any help would be apreciated, thanks

Comment: JavaScript regular expressions are enclosed in slashes (`/.../`) unless you use the `RegExp()` constructor, which expects a string(`"..."`). You can't just type random characters in the middle of your script ;-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your text will always look like that, you can use this:

```
function returnNewString(oldString) {
    return oldString.match(/[-\d]+/);
}
```

If, on the other hand, you might have a string like `/Date(+62135596800000+0100)/` or like `/Date(62135596800000+0100)/`, then you should use this:

```
function returnNewString(oldString) {
    return oldString.match(/(?:-|\+)?\d+/);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'/Date(-62135596800000+0100)/'.replace(/\/Date\((.*?)\+.*\)\//, '$1');
```

Explanation: The unescaped parentheses match the part between the opening parenthesis in your string and the plus sign, which is the only thing (`$1`) the whole string is replaced with.

Answer (score 0):

`/Date((-?\d+)+\d+)/`
Group 1 will contain the desired portion of your string.

For example, if your input is "/Date(-62135596800000+0100)/" then

Group 0 (entire match) will be "/Date(-62135596800000+0100)/" and
Group 1 will be -62135596800000